# How to split the string before the 2nd occurrence of a character in Java

Tags: java, string, function, split

I have:

```
1234 2345 3456 4567
```

When I try `String.split(" ",2)`, I get:

```
{1234} , {2345 3456 4567}
```

But I need:

```
{1234},{2345}
```

I want only the first two elements. How do I implement this in Java?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:This is just one line of a huge dataset.

Comment: How about splitting on every space and after taking just the first 2 element of the resulting array ?

Comment: That'd be a little less efficient. I've already given it a thought.

Comment: space wise or time wise ? Sometimes I prefer giving up on efficiency instead of reinventing the weel

Comment: Space wise and "code" wise.

Answer (score 8):

I assume you need first two string, then do the following:

```
    String[] res = Arrays.copyOfRange(string.split(" "), 0, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:-

```
String[] s=string.split("");
s[2]=null;
s[3]=null;
```

Now you only have {1234},{2345}

OR the better way , part the String itself then apply split()

```
String s=string.substring(string.indexOf("1"),string.indexOf("5")+1);// +1 for including the 5
s.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have any options, one is to do the split and copy the first 2 results.

The next code has the next output:

First two:
1234

2345

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input="1234 2345 3456 4567";

    String[] parts= input.split(" ");
    String[] firstTwoEntries = Arrays.copyOf(parts, 2);

    System.out.println("First two: ");
    System.out.println("----------");
    for(String entry:firstTwoEntries){
        System.out.println(entry);
    }
    System.out.println("----------");
}
```

Another is to replace the original string with a regexp and after do the split:

Result of the next code(we replace the space with ":":

Filtered: 1234:2345

First two:

1234

2345

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input="1234 2345 3456 4567";

    //we find first 2 and separate with :
    String filteredInput= input.replaceFirst("^([^\\s]*)\\s([^\\s]*)\\s.*$", "$1:$2");
    System.out.println("Filtered: "+filteredInput);

    String[] parts= filteredInput.split(":");
    System.out.println("First two: ");
    System.out.println("--------");
    for(String part:parts){
        System.out.println(part);
    }
    System.out.println("--------");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the substring that contains what you want, by calling `indexOf` twice.
2. Use `split()` on just that substring.

Here is one alternate solution that uses only `indexOf` and `substring`.

```
public class Program{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "1234 2345 3456 4567";
        int firstIndex = input.indexOf(" ");
        int secondIndex = input.indexOf(" ", firstIndex + 1);
        String[] output = new String[] {input.substring(0, firstIndex),
            input.substring(firstIndex+1, secondIndex)};
        System.out.println(output[0]);
        System.out.println(output[1]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1234
2345
```

Comment: I know ,I thought about that but is there a simpler solution?

Comment: @kaushaya, Not really, no. As far as I know, there's no library function for this.

Comment: @kaushaya, I just added a second solution that does not use string.split at all. If you care about speed you should probably benchmark this one against the one that does the `split` followed by `Arrays.copyOfRange()` and use whichever is faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
String input="1234 5678 9012 3456";
String[] result=Arrays.copyOf(input.split(" "),2);
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

The easiset (but not fastest) is to first split the string

```
String test = "123 2345 3456 4567"
String[] splitted = test.split(" ");
```

and the slice the resulting array:

```
String[] result = Arrays.copyOfRange(splitted, 2);
```

This will work well in most cases. The only problem might be, when the intermediate array gets really huge. You will then have lots of intermediate memory, that the garbage collector has to clean up. But with modern optimizations (like escape analysis) even this might not have a big performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

Another **single line solution** would be:

Let's suppose you have this:

```
String a="1234 2343545 356 88";
```

So, the single line command would  be:

```
String b[]=a.substring(0,a.indexOf(" ",a.indexOf(" ")+1)).split(" ");
```

Now you have **"b"** as an Array of the two first occurrences:

```
b[0] //1234
b[1] //2343545
```