# How to split a string at a specific point?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am finding it difficult to split my string the way I want, none of the answers on this platform meets my requirement.

I have string:

```
String s = "1 13 3 1 111 0 18 3";
```

What I want is to split it and print the two parts seperately.

I want to split it where there is a space, and specifying which space should the split occurs.

For example split the string at space number 4, to print first part: `1 13 3 1`

And second part: `111 0 18 3`

Comment: "Non of the answers on this platform meets my requirement." <- If every programming problem would already be solved and you could just get the code from somewhere on the internet there wouldn't be need for software developers. It's kind of our job to find solutions to problems that don't exist yet. So not finding the exact solution to your problem is what you should expect and it should not stop you from trying to solve the problem yourself. Have you at least tried to think about how you could solve this problem yourself by using the existing string methods you know of?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split the string before the 2nd occurrence of a character in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324761/how-to-split-the-string-before-the-2nd-occurrence-of-a-character-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a library only for this one task would be too much of a good thing, but if you happen to use the `org.apache.commons.lang3.*` library anyway you can use the method `StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf`:

```
String myString = "1 13 3 1 111 0 18 3";
int indexOf4thSpace = StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(myString, " ", 4);

System.out.println(myString.substring(0,indexOf4thSpace));
System.out.println(myString.substring(indexOf4thSpace + 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like **algo** problem to me.

**Here is my solution.** This is not the most efficient algo but I did it so that it is very simple for you to understand.

```
    String s = "1 13 3 1 111 0 18 3";
    String[] spitedString = s.split(" "); //Split by white spaces

    int halfIndex = spitedString.length / 2; //Find the center index to divide the string into first and second half.

    String[] firstHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(spitedString, 0, halfIndex); //First half of String.
    String[] secondHalf = Arrays.copyOfRange(spitedString, halfIndex, spitedString.length - 1); //Second half of String.

    //You could loop through the parts 
    for(String c: firstHalf){
        System.out.println(c);
    }

    //Or put it into one String
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String c: secondHalf){
        sb.append(c); //append string
        sb.append(" "); //and append white space
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
```

**EDIT** OP's request " i may target the first space, or 5th one or any other for certain conditions, lets say i have int target = someIntCalue;".

Sure, the logic is the same, just replace `halfIndex` with your `targetIndex`. The idea is that `halfIndex` is the index to divide the String.

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

Comment: The problem now is, um not always dividing the string by half, i may target the first space, or 5th one or any other for certain conditions,  lets say i have int target = someIntCalue; target is the point at which i want to implement my split. For example target  =  3;

Comment: @PowerO i have updated my answer to meet your needs.

Comment: Confusing line: int halfIndex = spitedString.length / 2;

Comment: @PowerO int halfIndex = spitedString.length / 2; <-- is when you split the string in to two equal halfs. if you want to split at target = 3, just let halfIndex = 3.

Comment: Doesn't it divide by exactly half? Can you use this example, i want to split on third space

Comment: Yes, please see my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "43241 142343 33 1 111 0 18 3";
       int counter = 0;
       int target = 4;
       int index = 0;

       for( char c : s.toCharArray() ){
           if(c == ' '){ //find the space
               counter++;

               if(counter == target){ //nth occurrence of the target
                   break;
               }
           }
           index++;
       }

       String split1 = s.substring(0,index);
       String split2 = s.substring(index);

       System.out.println( split1.trim() );
       System.out.println( split2.trim() );
```

Changing the value of `target` is all you need to do.

The output is

```
43241 142343 33 1

111 0 18 3
```

Comment: This is it, but problem now is, there are no more space on my result string, how can i add them back, like:1  2  3  9, what am getting now is 1239 as one word/number

Comment: Please provide more detailed description to reproduce the issue you are facing.

Comment: Um saying the extracted string has no spaces anymore, i need thos spaces. I have successfully extracted my desired string using your code, but it does not have spaces any more

Comment: My output is normal ( In the case of `target` is 4)
```43241 142343 33 1<line break>111 0 18 3
```

So I would like to know what you use for the `s` and `target` that will cause the issue? Because the code works fine for me in most case that I have tested.

Comment: Exactly your code as it is is what I have copied.

Comment: That is weird. I does not find any way that can reproduce issue that you facing.

Comment: Is there any suggestion you may give me to solve the problem